# How do I create an SQL trigger that has an if-condition?

Tags: mysql

I'm taking an introductory databases course in college right now, and we're tasked with creating a basic Flickr clone web app. I've created all my tables, but I can't seem to properly create triggers. My partner has not been able to figure out this problem either. One condition for this app is that the owner of an album cannot change. Currently, our trigger looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ownerChange
    BEFORE UPDATE ON Albums
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        -- owner is a column of the Albums table
        IF (NEW.owner <> OLD.owner) THEN
            -- Our textbook mentions using "RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR",
            -- but the darn book is 20 years old, and Googling suggests
            -- using SIGNAL instead.
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Changing album owner is not allowed.'
        END IF
    END
```

If I drop the database and try to cleanly source the schema containing this trigger, the tables are all created just fine, but I receive

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'END IF
    END' at line 75
```

I'm using MySQL version 8.0.23.

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: your end if and your siglanl nneds a semicolon at the end

Comment: @nbk So I tried that and I'm still getting syntax errors. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are missing two semicolons

like seen in the example.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Albums (
>   `owner` INTEGER
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER ownerChange
>     BEFORE UPDATE ON Albums
>     FOR EACH ROW
>     BEGIN
>         -- owner is a column of the Albums table
>         IF (NEW.owner <> OLD.owner) THEN
>             -- Our textbook mentions using "RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR",
>             -- but the darn book is 20 years old, and Googling suggests
>             -- using SIGNAL instead.
>             SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Changing album owner is not allowed.';
>         END IF;
>     END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Albums VALUES (1);
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE Albums SET owner = 2 WHERE owner = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> Changing album owner is not allowed.
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Albums;
> ```
>
> ```
> | owner |
> | ----: |
> |     1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72d939be62711f17dce6a12253b73e28)*

outside of mysql Workbench, you need also DELIMITER

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ownerChange
    BEFORE UPDATE ON Albums
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        -- owner is a column of the Albums table
        IF (NEW.owner <> OLD.owner) THEN
            -- Our textbook mentions using "RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR",
            -- but the darn book is 20 years old, and Googling suggests
            -- using SIGNAL instead.
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Changing album owner is not allowed.';
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: So I tried this, exactly as given, and it still doesn't work. `mysql --version` outputs `mysql  Ver 8.0.23 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)`. What should my next steps be?

Comment: If it helps, here's a paste of my schema: https://pastebin.com/LfWpbXQr

Comment: @Andrew you have a typo it must be `SET MESSAGE_TEXT =` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e5596fd711c9e88e56f9d4ec60f5fff please be next time more care full

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you so much for your help!